# Lamb shift at the level of four-potential seems to violate causality

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, causality

In QED, it is well known that in a suitable renormalization scheme, and in a static case, the potential energy taking into account the Lamb shift of the electron around the nucleus of charge $Ze$ in a hydrogen-like atom is given by:
\begin{equation}
E_\text{pot} = -4\pi Z\alpha \int d^3 x |\Psi(x)|^2 \left( \frac{1}{4\pi r}+\frac{\alpha}{15\pi m_e^2}\delta^{(3)}(x) \right) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Where $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant, and $|\Psi|^2 \equiv \Psi^\dagger\Psi$ is the squared norm of the electron-positron field.

Long ago I was interested in the non-static case, and back then I found a surprising result that I was only able to interpret as a field-field interaction that does not depend on the position space. The calculation goes as follows.

The photon propagator at one loop in the Feynman 't Hooft gauge condition is:
\begin{align}
D^{\mu \nu}(k)=&\frac{-i}{k^2+i\epsilon}(-i\Pi^{\mu \nu}(k))\frac{-i}{k^2+i\epsilon}
\\
\stackrel{m^2 \gg |k^2|}{=}&\frac{-i}{k^2+i\epsilon} \eta^{\mu \nu} \left[ 1-\Delta_3^F+\frac{\alpha}{3\pi}\ln \left( \frac{m^2}{\mu^2} \right)-\frac{\alpha}{15\pi}\frac{k^2}{m^2} \right]+k^\mu k^\nu \mathcal{T}(k) \tag{2}
\end{align}
Where $\Delta^F_3$ is the finite part of the coupling renormalization constant, and $k^\mu k^\nu \mathcal{T}(k)$ is a gauge term my book said we can neglect (but my book was doing the calculation in the static case, and I (maybe wrongly?) assumed we could do the same in the non-static case). Choosing appropriately $\Delta_3^F$ to compensate the $\ln$, we have the scalar Green function $G$:
\begin{equation}
G(x)=\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \left[ \frac{1}{k^2+i\epsilon}- \frac{\alpha}{15\pi m^2}\frac{k^2}{k^2+i\epsilon} \right]e^{-ikx} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
After doing a bit of calculation I obtain:
\begin{equation}
G(x)=-\theta(x^2)\frac{i}{4\pi^2 x^2}-\frac{\alpha}{15\pi m^2}\delta^{(4)}(x) \tag{4}
\end{equation}
One can then use this Green's function to find the four-potential since $A^\mu (x) = \int d^4 y G(x-y) j^\mu(y)$. After some contour manipulations to get rid of the Heaviside theta function I find:
\begin{equation}
A^\mu(x)=-\int d^3 y \frac{j^\mu (x^0 \pm |\vec{x}-\vec{y}|,\vec{y})}{4\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{y}|}-\frac{\alpha}{15\pi m^2}j^\mu (x^0, \vec{x}) \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Using $j^\mu = e\overline{\Psi} \gamma^\mu \Psi$ and placing ourselves in the static case, we recover equation $(1)$. But in the dynamical case, the second term of $(5)$ seems to violate causality as a change in the source induces instantaneously a change in the gauge field. I'm pretty sure my calculation $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ and correct, but I wonder if neglecting the "gauge" terms was a good idea? If my calculations are correct, then why do I have such a term?